# Force http in heroku

Tags: node.js, django, http, heroku, https

I have a node.js app in heroku , this app uses a Django API which is http, but the heroku app is https and cant make petitions to the API, I get this error

> xhr.js:177 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint (API HTTP URL). This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I just want to change the https://myapp.herokuapp.com/ to http://myapp.herokuapp.com/

Comment: "I just want to change the https://myapp.herokuapp.com/ to http://myapp.herokuapp.com/"—no you don't. You want to make your app work properly over HTTPS. It's 2021; there's no excuse to run over HTTP anymore. This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).